# Is it correct to pass two classes as arguments in NonStrictExpectations in JMockit?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, stub, jmockit, stubbing

Can we pass more than two class aruments in NonStrictExpectations. Like this

```
NonStrictExpcetations(A.class, B.class)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, no problem. Each class passed in will cause it to be partially mocked according to the expectations recorded inside the block.